# Fetch key inside a json object in php jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am returning a json data to jquery  using php. what i want is to access the keys inside the json. i followed a tutorial and used json stringify but im not able to access the keys.

**json data :**

```
[
    {"id":"1","movie_name":"spiderman","releases_on":"20th August 2018"},
    {"id":"2","movie_name":"batman","releases_on":"21st August 2018"},
    {"id":"3","movie_name":"fast and furious 6","releases_on":"22nd August 2018"}
]
```

**code in jquery:**

```
var json = data;
var obj = JSON.stringify(json);
console.log(obj[1].id);
```

Comment: The data is an array, so you need to access by index, `yourObj[0].id` for example

Comment: once this data is returned by php this is how my jquery code looks like

    var json = data;

    var obj = JSON.stringify(json);
    console.log(obj[1].id);

and in console it says "undefined"

Comment: Please edit the question to include your jQuery code. You definitely don't need `JSON.stringify()` in there, though. Try just `data[1].id`

Comment: It is an array simple access it with an index, first you do something like json_decode('[
    {"id":"1","movie_name":"spiderman","releases_on":"20th August 2018"},
    {"id":"2","movie_name":"batman","releases_on":"21st August 2018"},
    {"id":"3","movie_name":"fast and furious 6","releases_on":"22nd August 2018"}
]');

Then you access them with array syntax

Comment: Thanks for your resonse @shakeelosmani

i want to print keys on clientside using jquery. I tried 

    var json_array = data;
    console.log(json_array[1].id);

but this returns undefined. 

Json_decode won't work on client side.

Comment: @sid Please edit your question to include your current jQuery AJAX code. That's the last piece of the puzzle we need to see in order to help you

Comment: If this is your json on client side you do not need to do anything. Test this code in console

var data = [
    {"id":"1","movie_name":"spiderman","releases_on":"20th August 2018"},
    {"id":"2","movie_name":"batman","releases_on":"21st August 2018"},
    {"id":"3","movie_name":"fast and furious 6","releases_on":"22nd August 2018"}
];

console.log(data[0].id);

Comment: Thank you @shakeelosmani. You suggestion about json.parse works properly!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use JSON.parse(json).
then, you can do it.

Comment: @sid select! my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify()` will take your JSON object and convert it to a JSON string (here which is response).

`JSON.parse()` will take stringified JSON and convert it to object so that you can access via `.` operator

for example,

```
var a = { name: "John", age: 20 }
console.log(typeof a)   // object
var out = JSON.stringify(a)
console.log(typeof out)  // string
var res = JSON.parse(out) 
console.log(typeof res)  // object
```

I hope you got it....